# Pandas Nested functions: apply does not seem to recognize internal function

Tags: python, pandas, nested, apply

I have a nested function such that

```
def f(l):
  def g(index):
      print index   
  l.apply(lambda x :x if x else g(x.name))
```

g(index) is an internal function of f(x). l is a 'pandas.core.series.Series' object which contains sets

```
>>> linked_on
1    set([xyz.com])
3    set([])
Name: EMAIL_ID, dtype: object
```

It seems like the internal function is not being recognized by the program and it just flows through in the else case without affecting anything. What I want is for the apply to call the internal function on the value if the set is empty. I put a breakpoint in the function but it never goes into it. When I try to break outside and run the function in the interpreter I get

```
NameError: global name 'g' is not defined
```

But I never get this error while running the code as is and it just flows through without giving any errors but also not going into the internal function. Any help into explaining this phenomenon will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to ultimately do something like: `np.where(l, l, 'something else')` ?

Comment: I am trying to find empty sets in my series and do something with them. Will look into np.where but I am confused as to why the internal function isn't being recognized

Comment: @piRSquared thanks. i felt like it wasn't going anywhere based on the comments it was generating so I deleted it